# Get the CodeFile property on aspx

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can you get the string on the Code File property of a aspx file using a javascript? I was trying `alert(document.codefile);` but it just returns `undefined`.

Comment: You can't... But there probably better way to achieve whatever you are trying to do with this call - consider updating your post with actual goal.

Comment: what do u want to do ?

Comment: Maybe you can state why you are trying to achieve this behavior instead of asking how to do this :). There might be millions of other (better) ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the window's location, you can use a by-convention approach.  There is no way to grab it in the way you showed above because javascript knows nothing of a server.

```
var loc = window.location + '.aspx';
//or .ascx depending
```

I don't know this would have any value for you, as it's useful to asp.net, but not JS.